# GCC installed inside conda ignores LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: gcc, anaconda, linker, shared-libraries, conda

I installed GCC into a conda environment:

```
conda create -n gccenv gcc_linux-64=8.4.0 gxx_linux-64=8.4.0
```

When I set `LIBRARY_PATH`, it is only picked up by the system GCC however:

```
conda activate gccenv
export LIBRARY_PATH=/foo/bar

/usr/bin/g++ --print-search-dirs | tr ':' $'\n'

OUTPUT: libraries
 =/foo/bar/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/
/foo/bar/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/foo/bar/../lib/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/9/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/lib/../lib/
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/../lib/
/foo/bar/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../
/lib/
/usr/lib/

~/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-g++ --print-search-dirs | tr ':' $'\n'

OUTPUT: libraries
 =/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../lib/gcc/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/../lib/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/
/home/allgeuer/anaconda3/envs/gccenv/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/
```

When I try to compile an open source project with the conda GCC, it fails to find a library in the `/foo/bar` directory and exits with a linker error. How can I get the conda GCC (which is the exact version I need of GCC) to listen to `LIBRARY_PATH`?